# How to draw rounded raised and sunken edges of control?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, draw

I need a way to draw rounded raised and sunken corner edges on a custom control.  Currently, I am using ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D, but of course the corners are squared off and looks terrible. How can this be done?  Also, this project is not allowed to use any PInvoke calls.

Comment: i assume this isn't a web project...

Comment: Does it have to be a 3d border, or would a solid color border be ok?

Answer (score 2):

you have to draw it manually via a series of arcs and lines.  the easiest way is to add them to a **Path** and use **Graphics.DrawPath**(...)

[check out this post in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/bcb3bd60-811c-430b-996d-9e082d4bf9ab)